# How to add index to already built database on the server?

Tags: mysql, django, indexing

How do I add indexes to a database that is already created?

I'm a newbie to MYSQL and built a DB without any indexes in Django that is really really slow.

I'm trying to add indexes. The problem is that I need to filter by a foreign key. The query is painfully slow (think 20-25 seconds), even though the tables are not big (product = 1 million, another is 10k).

Here is my Django code:

```
#large db (Product) filtered by foreign key (another__id)
Product.objects.filter(another__id='x')
```

Should I put an index on the "id" in the *another* table or the "another" column in the *product* table?

Do I create an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX "another" ON Product
```

Since this is on the server, what kind of lock should I do?

Comment: MySQL requires an index on the referenced column of a foreign key, and automatically creates one on the referencing column. So both columns should already have an index. If you want to optmize your queries, start by identifying the slow queries, then have a look are their explain plans...

Comment: I have identified the slow queries, but cannot figure out why they are slow. This product query takes about 20-25 seconds to run but only has 1 million rows and the another table has about 10k rows. How do I figure out why it's slow through Django?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT ...` so that I won't have to guess what Django is doing.